# How to write a batch to run an executable file with a config file (ini)?

Tags: batch-file

I have an executable file which I am able to run it in CMD with a config file (ini).

```
(C:\User\ABC.exe --apps_config XYZ.ini)
```

I am trying to create a batch file for this command.
I know I can use START command to run a regular exe file. 
(Ex. `START C:\User\ABC.exe`) but I don't know how to create a batch file to run ABC.EXE with associated config file (.ini).

Comment: There's no difference, (except when a quoted argument is involved, start interprets the 1st quoted argument as the window title).

Comment: you don't need `start` to start an `.EXE`. Copy the same command you use on command line into a batch file.

Comment: Actually, a quoted argument is involved because of the file path. Ex. `C:\Program Files 86\New Folder\ABC.exe` so I have to use quotes for the directory which has **space** in its name. Could you advise?

Comment: `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\New Folder\ABC.exe" --apps_config "XYZ.ini"`